Cannot open webp picture in html
I just cannot display a .webp file.
Html code:
<body>
Test Webp/JPG images: <br /><br />
Image1 Webp (1.4 MB):<br />
<picture>
  <source type="image/webp" media="(min-width:650px)" srcset="../../240806_2066_GotaHovratt_450.webp" style="width:auto;">
  <img src="../../240806_2066_GotaHovratt_full.jpg" >
</picture>
<br /><br />
Image2, largest jpg (17 MB):<br />
<img src="../../240806_2066_GotaHovratt_full.jpg" width="1200" >
<br /><br />
Image3, highres jpg (1.2 MB): <br />
<img src="../Highres/240806_2066_GotaHovratt_20.jpg" width="1200" >
</body>

URL: arxfoto.se/data/_testwebp.html
I am using the w3schools.com HTML <picture> Tag example, and using Google Chrome which supports webp.
The 240806_2066_GotaHovratt_full.jpg file that is the backup - if the webp file is not functioning - is not either displayed, but it is displayed as a normal jpg file in an <img> tag. There is nothing wrong with the path, but the picture tag does not seem to work for me. What am I doing wrong?

Are you certain — what if you change the file completely to a different image to make it easier to debug? Are you able to upload your example somewhere?

Checkout the URL provided for example

The example you linked has the webp image at https://arxfoto.se/240806_2066_GotaHovratt_450.webp, which shows an HTTP 404 error when opened in a new tab. I assume you must have a typo.

Thanks all! It seems that my online server gives error 404 because of the extension (webp). I will talk to my provider and come back tomorrow!

Why are there red flags at some comments here?

And this test shows that a 1.6 MB webp image almost equals a 17 MB jpg version of the same image.
That’s a useful difference in size.

It is strange that me having a problem with not knowing that some used MIME types maybe are not recognized in all servers can lead someone to red flag my post and block my account.
Trying to understand and solve the problem seems more constructive than to block someone for asking a question that you maybe don’t understand.
Could you please remove the red flags?

A comment on the tag .
It offers a fallback to use a jpg file if the webp file cannot be loaded.
But that fallback obviously only is triggered if the system (browser) does not handle the MIME type webp.
If the  tag is used for instance in Chrome the fallback does not take the jpg file even if the webp file does not exist.
So this fallback function is limited.

@Djave - why was this post flagged?/ Lars M

@Prateekshit Jaiswal - why was this post flagged?

@Peter Pointer - why was this post flagged?

After my provider’s technician returned from his vacation I have now got this information:
The MIME type .webp is not automatically supported in IIS on their server. They would like to keep their IIS with the original settings. The MIME type “.Webp” is a recent addition and to have it supported I must put following code in my web.config file on my website:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
      <staticContent>
         <mimeMap fileExtension=".webp" mimeType="image/webp" />
      </staticContent>
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>

After doing that I can also have .webp images displayed on my website. Problem solved.
